# Fastest framework / method to perform multiple calculations on 11m rows x 12 columns of data from a csv

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv

I have a CSV that is supplied from a 3rd party every morning. That csv requires processing, and I'm looking for recommendations as to how those familiar with data science / big data management would approach the problem.

I more than likely need to pair two data sources based on a common field - in a database I would use a pair.

Speed is the main goal - though manageable scripting would also be beneficial. Postgres is not winning in the manageable script part in my books. More on that below.

**Incoming data:**
CSV, Approx 12 columns, 11m rows.

**Incoming Data Types:**
Text, Integer, Decimal, DateTime

**Calculations:**
Add as new columns.
Add, Subtract, Multiply, Exponential.

**Sorting / Group_By:**
The ability to select the maximum value from sub groups. Eg: For Each GROUP_ID, select the 'row' of data (each row is a 1hr interval) that has the maximum intensity (numeric).

For example:

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| ID |     TIMEDATE     | Intensity |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2019/01/01_12:00 |         1 |
|  1 | 2019/01/01_13:00 |         5 |
|  1 | 2019/01/01_14:00 |         3 |
|  1 | 2019/01/01_15:00 |         2 |
|  3 | 2019/01/01_12:00 |        10 |
|  3 | 2019/01/01_13:00 |        50 |
|  3 | 2019/01/01_14:00 |        30 |
|  3 | 2019/01/01_15:00 |        20 |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

Can be calculated to:

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| ID |     TIMEDATE     | Intensity |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2019/01/01_13:00 |         5 |
|  3 | 2019/01/01_13:00 |        50 |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

**Calculations are iterative:**
Column A * Column B = Column C. 
Column D = Column A + Column C.
Column E = Column B ^ Column D.

**Outgoing Data:**
Either to DB Table, or to CSV. 
Potentially 25 columns or more.

**The options:**
I have available and am loosely familiar with in house are Python/Pandas/Anaconda/etc, PostgreSQL 12, MS MSQL (would prefer not to use if possible). 
I am, to some extent, able to use other software too.

**Tests to date:**
Using Tableau to run the calculations - slow. Takes 40 mins. 
Using Postgres 10 to run 1/3 of the calculations - slow. Takes 15 mins. 
Both these products can handle pairing tables. 
Postgres does not support using variables in calculating column values for each row of data, meaning I wind up with a rats nest of a script.

**Hardware/System:**
128gb ram + 44 physical cores available on a single machine. Nvidia Cuda available. Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: +1 for successfully measuring the time that processing needs currently. -1 because you don't specify an acceptable time. What are you looking for? Processing in 13 minutes ok? Or 1 minute? Or 5 seconds? How large is the CSV? "Text" can be huge. If it's 200 GB of text, it will definitely be slow, no matter how many cores you have.

Comment: Good point @ThomasWeller.
1gb of text. As for processing time, I'm not sure. Overnight I've been playing with Python/Pandas/Dask and am starting to see some success in reducing processing times, and also been able to perform calculated column on calculated column actions. After introducing 2 calculated columns the run time is 8-9 seconds, excluding a final disk write. I'm curious to see how that extends out when there's more columns and I introduce some joins. Sub 1 minute is acceptable.

Comment: At 100 MB/s disk speed, that's 10 seconds read time and 10 seconds write time, leaving 40 seconds for the calculations, ok? I have 96 GB RAM, so I could perform some tests. Do you have sample data I could use?